# How do I rewrite this line using method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working with SMO and I have this line of code:

```
var results = (from User user in database.Users
    where user.LoginType == LoginType.WindowsUser
    select new { user.Name, user.Login }).ToList();
```

But for whatever reason, I cannot write the query like this:

```
var results = database.Users
              .Where(user => user.LoginType == LoginType.WindowsUser)
              .Select(user => new { Name = user.Name, Login = user.Login })
              .ToList();
```

The error I get is `'UserCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'UserCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

But as far as as I can see, both these statements are identical.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file?  `Where` and `Select` are extension methods.

Comment: @BrianRogers: That would still fail with the query expression form as well - writing a query expression doesn't implicitly import any namespaces.

Comment: Yes. It won't let me use query syntax otherwise. I get the error `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'UserCollection'.  'Cast' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they're *very slightly* different. Because you've got an explicitly-typed range variable here:

```
from User user in database.Users
```

your query is equivalent to:

```
var results = database.Users
                      .Cast<User>();
                      .Where(user => user.LoginType == LoginType.WindowsUser)
                      .Select(user => new { user.Name, user.Login })
                      .ToList();
```

Presumably your `UserCollection` type implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<User>` - which is why you need the cast.

You can provoke the same error with a query expression by leaving the range variable implicitly typed:

```
// This will fail
var results = (from user in database.Users
               where user.LoginType == LoginType.WindowsUser
               select new { user.Name, user.Login }).ToList();
```